# Quotients and extensions of scalars in polynomial algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra

Let $K$ be a ring, $L$ an extension of $K$, and $I$ an ideal of $K[X_1,...,X_n]$. Is it true that

$$ L[X_1,...,X_n]/(IL[X_1,...,X_n]) \cong (K[X_1,...,X_n]/I) \otimes_K L \ \ ?$$

(additional question: does something similar hold more generally, for instance when $K$ is a ring and $L$ a $K$-algebra (and $K$ does not necessarily inject into $L$)?)

I have troubles applying general commutative algebra machinery because the situation is very specific: we have an identification $K[X_1,...,X_n] \otimes_K L \cong L[X_1,...,X_n]$, into which $K[X_1,...,X_n]$ injects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: As a scalar extension, the first step is that
$L[X] \simeq K[X]\otimes_K L$.

Moreover, for the ideal, $I L[X] \simeq I\otimes_K L$.

Thus $L[X]/(IL[X]) \simeq (K[X]\otimes_K L) / (I\otimes_KL)\simeq (K[X]/I)\otimes_K L$.

Comment: Ok thanks. So I guess you can do this (in general for algebras) whenever $K$ injects into $L$ and $L$ is $K$-flat? Or even in complete generality?

Comment: I guess it should hold in complete generality, but then $I \otimes_K L$ should be replaced by its image in the second term of the last line