# Why $\operatorname{Proj}\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]/(y^2z+yz^2-x^3+xz^2)$ is fibered surface over $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading the Liu's Algebraic Geometry and arithmetic curves, p.348, Example 3.2. and stuck at some point.

**Definition 3.1** ( In his book p.347 ). Let $S$ be a Dedekind scheme. We call an integral, projective, flat $S$-scheme $\pi : X \to S$ of dimension $2$ a *fibered surface over $S$.* The generic point of $S$ will be denoted by $\eta$. We call $X_{\eta}$ the *generic fiber of $X$.* A fiber $X_s$ with $s\in S$ closed is called a *closed fiber*. When $\operatorname{dim}S=1$, $X$ is called a *projective flat $S$-curve* (see Lemma  3.3). **Note that the flatness of $\pi$ is equivalent to the surjectivity of $\pi$.** (C.f. [Fibered surface is flat if and only if it surjects onto the base](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2651544/fibered-surface-is-flat-if-and-only-if-it-surjects-onto-the-base/2651615#2651615) ) We will say that $X$ is *normal* (resp. *regular*) *fibered surface* if $X$ is normal (resp. regular).

**Example 3.2.** Let $S:= \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$ and $X:=\operatorname{Proj}\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]/(y^2z+yz^2-x^3+xz^2)$. Let us show that $X$ is a normal fibered surface. **The only point needing verification is that $X$ is normal.** ( Next argument for showing normality is omitted ).

I don't understand why the bold statement is true. $X$ is integral, projective scheme (over $S$).

My question is, for $X$ to become fibered surface over $S$,

- **Q.1.** Why $X$ has dimension $2$?

**EDIT :** First attempt to the first question. Note that by the Liu's book, p.53, Lemma 3.41, letting $I :=(f(x,y,z):=y^2z+yz^2-x^3+xz^2)$,
$ \operatorname{Proj}\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]/I$ is isomorphic to a closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^{2}_{\mathbb{Z}}$, with support ( i.e., with underlying topological space) $V_{+}(I)$.

So, $\dim \operatorname{Proj}\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]/I = \dim V_{+}(I)$ and it suffices to show that $\dim V_{+}(I)=2$. First note that $V_{+}(I)$ is a proper closed subset of $\mathbb{P}^{2}_{\mathbb{Z}}$ (True?). So,

$$  \dim V_{+}(I) < \dim \mathbb{P}^{2}_{\mathbb{Z}} = \dim Z + 2 = 3 .$$

so that $\dim V_{+}(I) \le 2$. So it suffices to show that $ 2 \le \dim V_{+}(I)$.

Now I arrange some preliminary definitions for showing this.

We set $A_{+} := \oplus_{d \ge 1} A_d$. This is a graded ideal. More generally, if $I \subseteq A$ is a homogeneous ideal, we set $I_{+} := I \cap A_{+}$. This is again a homogeneous ideal. A homogeneous prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \subset A$ is called *relevant* if it does not contain $A_{+}$, i.e., if $\mathfrak{p}_{+} \subsetneq A_{+}$.

> Proposition 13.4. (Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, p.369) Let $A$ be a graded ring. For a subset $Y \subseteq \operatorname{Proj}A$ define

$$ I_{+}(Y) := (\cap_{\mathfrak{p} \in Y} \mathfrak{p}) \cap A_{+}.$$

> (2) The maps $Y \mapsto I_{+}(Y)$ and $I \mapsto V_{+}(I)$ define mutually inverse, inclusion reversing bijections between the set of homogeneous ideals $I \subseteq A_{+}$ such that $I=\operatorname{rad}(I)_{+}$ and the set of closed subsets of $\operatorname{Proj}A$.

> Via this bijection, the closed irreducible subsets correspond to ideals of the form $\mathfrak{p}_{+}$, where $\mathfrak{p}$ is relevant prime ideal.

Note that $\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]_{+} = (x,y,z)$ (True?). And note that the above $I$ is homogeneous relevant prime ( In fact $I$ is a prime ideal since $f(x,y,z):=y^2z+yz^2-x^3+xz^2$ can be viewed as $-x^3 + z^2 x + (y^2z +yz^2) \in \mathbb{Z}[y,z][x]$ and applying the Eisenstein's Criterion ) ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]$ such that $I = I \cap \mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]_{+} =: I_{+}$.

So we have $I = I_{+}(V_{+}(I))$. Note that if we can find two relevant prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}_1$, $\mathfrak{p}_2$ such that

$$I = I_{+}(V_{+}(I)) \subsetneq \mathfrak{p}_{1, +} \subsetneq \mathfrak{p}_{2, +}$$,
then by the above inclusion reversing bijection, we obtain chain of closed irreducible subsets

$$ V_{+}(\mathfrak{p}_{2, +}) \subsetneq V_{+}(\mathfrak{p}_{1, +}) \subsetneq V_{+}(I) .$$

( $\divideontimes$ If $C \subseteq X$ is closed and $F \subseteq X$ is closed irreducible subset in $X$ such that $F \subseteq C$, then $F$ is closed irreducible in $C$. )

And so we have $ 2 \le \dim V_{+}(I)$. And we really can find such $\mathfrak{p}_1$, $\mathfrak{p}_2$ ?

Is it possible?

**EDIT** : Yes. It seems possible. Let $\mathfrak{p}_1 := (f, x,z)$ and $\mathfrak{p}_2:= (f,x,z,7y,7)$ where $f(x,y,z):=y^2z+yz^2-x^3+xz^2$. Such ideals may works. C.f. [Are there homogeneous prime ideals $p_1 , p_2 \nsupseteq (x,y,z)$ such that $I:=(y^2z+yz^2-x^3+xz^2) \subsetneq p_{1,+} \subsetneq p_{2,+}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4775159/are-there-homogeneous-prime-ideals-p-1-p-2-nsupseteq-x-y-z-such-that-i/4780570#4780570) .

- **Q.2.** why $X$ is flat over $S$? Or equivalently (as the bold statement in the above definition 3.1.), why $X$ is surjective over $S$?

Here I think that the morphism $\pi : X\to S$ is as : [What is explicit description of the structure morphism $\operatorname{Proj}A \to \operatorname{Spec}R$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4771620/what-is-explicit-description-of-the-structure-morphism-operatornameproja-to).

**EDIT :** *First attempt for the question 2* : I tried to show the flatness of $X$ over $S$ directly. Note https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01U5 and  https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AUW. From these, it sufficient to show that there is an open cover $X = \pi^{-1}(S) = \cup_{ i \in I} U_i$ such that $\mathbb{Z} = \mathcal{O}_S(S) \to \mathcal{O}_X(U_i)$ is torsion free for all $i\in I$. In particular, note that $X = \cup _{i \in I} D_{+}(f_i)$ where $f_i$ is homogeneous elements of $A_{+}$ where $A:= \mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]/(y^2z+yz^2-x^3+xz^2)$.

My question is, the induced ring maps $\mathbb{Z} = \mathcal{O}_S(S) \to \mathcal{O}_X(D_{+}(f_i)) = A_{(f_i)}$ is torsion free ? If so we are done.

*Second attempt for the question 2* : I tried to show the surjectivity of the $\pi : X \to S$ which is equivalent to the flatness, as I mentioned above. As I linked [What is explicit description of the structure morphism $\operatorname{Proj}A \to \operatorname{Spec}R$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4771620/what-is-explicit-description-of-the-structure-morphism-operatornameproja-to), the $\pi : X \to S$ is constructed from glueing next morphisms ( $f\in A_{+}$ homogeneous elements )

$$\psi_{f} : D_{+}(f) \xrightarrow{\cong} \operatorname{Spec}A_{(f)} \xrightarrow{^al_f} \operatorname{Spec}A_{0}= \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$$

, where $l_f : A_0 \to A_{(f)}$ be the natural map $a \mapsto \frac{a}{1}$. Note that $A_0 = \mathbb{Z}/(I\cap \mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}$.

To show the surjectivity of $\pi$, let $(p)$ be a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$. Then, my question is,

" does there exists homogeneous element $ f\in A_{+}$ and there exists $\mathfrak{q} \in \operatorname{Spec}A_{(f)}$ such that $^a l_f (\mathfrak{q}) = l_f^{-1}(\mathfrak{q}) = \{n \in A_0=\mathbb{Z} : \frac{n}{1} \in \mathfrak{q} \} = (p)$. "
?

Assume that $\{n \in A_0=\mathbb{Z} : \frac{n}{1} \in \mathfrak{q} \} = (p)$ is true for some $f$ and $\mathfrak{q}$. Then

1. If $np \in  (p)$, then $\frac{np}{1} \in \mathfrak{q}$.
2. If $n\in l_f^{-1}(\mathfrak{q})$ so that $\frac{n}{1}\in \mathfrak{q}$, then $n \in (p)$

From these, can we guess such $f \in A_{+}$ and $\mathfrak{q}$?

Can any one provide such $f \in A_{+}$ and $\mathfrak{q}$?

*Third attempt for the question 2* : Now I'm trying to show the sujectivity of $\pi :X \to S$ in other direction, helped from below hint of Aphelli.

Let $s= (p) \in S:= \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$. It suffices to show that $\pi^{-1}(s) \neq \varnothing$. Note that by the Liu's Algebraic geometry book, p.82, Proposition 3.1.9., we have ( $I:= (y^2z+yz^2−x^3+xz^2)$ )

$$ \pi^{-1}(s) \cong \operatorname{Proj}(\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]/I) \times _ {\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}}\operatorname{Spec}k(s) \cong \\ \operatorname{Proj}(\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]/I \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} k(s)) \cong \operatorname{Proj}( k(s)[x,y,z]/Ik(s)[x,y,z]) \cong V_{+}(Ik(s)[x,y,z]) \subseteq \mathbb{P}^{2}_{k(s)}$$

( C.f. The final isomorphism is true by the Liu's Lemma 2.3.41 (p.53). For the third isomorphism, see  [Quotients and extensions of scalars in polynomial algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3977380/quotients-and-extensions-of-scalars-in-polynomial-algebras). True? )

Note that $k(s) = \mathbb{Q}$ when $p=0$ and $k(s)=\mathbb{Z}/(p)$ when $p$ is prime number. So we can view the $Ik(s)[x,y,z]$ as the principal ideal generated by $f(x,y,z):= y^2z+yz^2-x^3+xz^2$ whose coefficients are  viewed as in $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$. If this polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$, then $V_{+}(Ik(s)[x,y,z]) \subseteq \mathbb{P}^{2}_{k(s)}$ is of codimension $1$ by the following thorem (Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, Corollary 5.42 ) so that it is nonempty **so that $\pi^{-1}(s)$ is nonempty and we are done**

> Corollary 5.42. Let $Z\subseteq \mathbb{P}^n_{k}$ be an integral closed subscheme. Then $Z$ is of codimension $1$ if and only if $Z=V_{+}(f)$ for an 'irreducible' homogeneous polynomial $f$.

**Q.** And $f(x,y,z)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$ ?

*Fourth attempt for the question 2* : Through communicating with Liu, I noticed that we may use next theorem ( Corollary 4.3.10 in Liu's book ) :

> Corollary 4.3.10. Let $Y$ be a Dedekind scheme, and $f:X\to Y$ be a non-constant morhpism ( i.e., $f(X)$ is not reduced to a point ) with $X$ integral. Then $f$ is flat.

So, my question is, the above $\pi : X \to S$ is non-constant? Is there any criteria for the non-constancy of a morphism ?

P.s. I am struggling with this issue for few hours. It will be appreciate for someone who can give a any crucial hint. Can anyone helps?

Comment: 1) it’s covered by affine open subsets of the form $\mathbb{Z}[u,v]$ quotiented by one equation, so this always has dimension two. 2) check explicitly that every fibre is nonempty (or that it has a cover by affine opens with torsion-free ring of functions).

Comment: Thank you. And some confusion. Can I ask more? 1) For the first comment, how can we find/cognize such covering? 2) For the second comment, I understood the latter comment, as finding an open cover $X= \pi^{-1}(S)=\cup_{i\in I} U_i$ such that $\mathbb{Z}=\mathcal{O}_S(S) \to  \mathcal{O}_{X}(U_i)$ is torsion free for all $i\in I$. (C.f. https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01U5, https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AUW ) True? And if so, then how can we find such covering? I think that I am begginer to the Proj construction. Can you give me more hint?

Comment: The best hint I can give you is to come back to the Proj construction (somewhere in Chap 2 in QL and revisited several times afterwards) and start doing the exercises (also at other points in the book where Proj is discussed, so probably Chap 3.3 and much of Chap 5). It will feel easier to work with Proj afterwards.

Comment: O,K, Thank you. And.. i write my own attempt to the first question. Can you see if you have time?

Comment: O.K. Aphelli. I added Edit for the second question to show the surjectivity of $\pi$ and still struggling with it for few hours. Can you help me if you have time ?! :)

Comment: Maybe you want $p_1=(x,y)$ and $p_2=(x, y,z)$. The ideals you chosen are obviously not prime.

Comment: Hint: given a morphism of schemes $X \rightarrow Y$, and $y \in Y$, the pre-images of $y$ are exactly in bijection with the points of the scheme $X \times_Y \operatorname{Spec}{k(y)}$. So you want to show that $\operatorname{Proj}{\mathbb{F}_p[x,y,z]/(y^2z+yz^2+xz^2-x^3)}$ is nonempty… I need to stress that this is *elementary* (as much as anything scheme-theoretic is) – as KReiser commented on the other question, you can’t just skip on this stuff and hope to correctly understand the more advanced parts of the theory.

Comment: @user26857 : I think that $p_2 = (x,y,z)$ is not allowed since each $p_1, p_2$ should satisfy $p_1 , p_2 \subsetneq \mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]_{+} = (x,y,z)$ (relevant ideals) How do you think about this? The above $\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]/\mathfrak{p}_1 \cong \mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]_{\le 2}$  and 
                    $\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]/\mathfrak{p}_2 \cong \mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]_{\le 1}$ in question are not true?

Comment: @Aphelli : Yes. I think that, like fool, I insist complicated route, leaving easy route :) Note that by the Liu's Algebraic geometry book, p.82, Proposition 3.1.9., we have $\operatorname{Proj}(\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]/I) \times _ {\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}}\operatorname{Spec}k(s) \cong \operatorname{Proj}(\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]/I \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} k(s)) = \operatorname{Proj}( k(s)[x,y,z]/Ik(s)[x,y,z])$ ( True? C.f. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3977380/quotients-and-extensions-of-scalars-in-polynomial-algebras ) You really mean this? And the final object is really nonempty?

Comment: @user26857 : I think that $\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]_{\le 2}$ and $\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]_{\le 1}$ are not subring of $\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]$. So I think that each quotients $\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]/p_1$ and $\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]/p_2$ are different objects. And how~.. Indeed is it really that each $p_1$ and $p_2$ I chosen are not prime is obvious? Why?

Comment: If $p$ is prime and $x^3\in p$, then what can we conclude?

Comment: @user26857 : I don't understand what relation exists between your sentence and my question :)  Through your sentence, what do you want to intent? How can we set $p_1$ and $p_2$?

Comment: As far as I can see your $p_1$ contains $x^3$.

Comment: @user26857 : Yes! Thank you. As you pointed out, my $p_1$ is not primes. I think that situation seems getting more and more confusing. Is there a simple setting for relavant primes $p_1$ and $p_2$ satisfying our demands?

Comment: @user26857 : And.. for the 'third attempt for the question 2', I reduced our required proof to the Abstract-algebra problem of showing the non-nilpotency of some rings. Again can you see? :)