# Can we describe $\operatorname{Spec}A_{(f)}$, where $A:= \mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]/(y^2z+yz^2-x^3+xz^2)$, more explicitly?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Literally, let $A:= \mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]/(y^2z+yz^2-x^3+xz^2)$ and $f \in A_{+}$ be a homogeneous element. Let $A_{(f)}$ be the subring of elements of degree zero of the localization $A_f$.

**Q.** Then can we describe $\operatorname{Spec}A_{(f)}$ more explicitly? How?

This problem is connected with my other question : [Why $\operatorname{Proj}\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]/(y^2z+yz^2-x^3+xz^2)$ is fibered surface over $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4772222/why-operatornameproj-mathbbzx-y-z-y2zyz2-x3xz2-is-fibered-surfa). Refer to the "second attempt for the question 2" at the bottom of the linked question.

Can anyone helps?

Comment: The fact that you are asking about fibered surfaces without knowing the basics of Proj is a big red flag that you have not spent enough time on your foundations. Please go back and review the construction and some easy work with projective varieties from the viewpoint of Proj before proceeding.